# Integration Test with 2 background services

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing, xunit, background-service

I have a dot net core project where I'm trying to write an integration test between my two `BackgroundServices`.

Below is my current `xUnit` test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task FileWatcherIntegration()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddHostedService<FileWatcherService>();
    services.AddHostedService<FailedTradesWorker>();
    services.AddSingleton(fileWatcherOptions);
    services.AddSingleton<ILogger<FileWatcherService>>(logger);

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


    var fileWatcher = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as FileWatcherService; 
    var tradeWorker = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as FailedTradesWorker;

    // act
    await tradeWorker.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    await fileWatcher.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    /* Ommited */


    await tradeWorker.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    await fileWatcher.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    // assert
    Assert.True(File.Exists(fileWatcherOptions.DestinationPathAndName));
}
```

My test fails on the line `var fileWatcher = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as FileWatcherService;` with the error message:  `Unable to resolve service for type`

What is the correct way to set up my services for this test?

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange:

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var tradeServiceProdiver = tradeServices.BuildServiceProvider();

var fileWatcher = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as FileWatcherService; 
var tradeWorker = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as FailedTradesWorker;
```

I would have used the one service provider and would have gotten the services by their type:

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var fileWatcher = serviceProvider.GetService<FileWatcherService>();
var tradeWorker = serviceProvider.GetService<FailedTradesWorker>();
```

Or I would have created interfaces that I could use like this:

```
public interface IFileWatcherService : IHostedService
{
   ...
}

public interface IFailedTradesWorker : IHostedService
{
   ...
}

services.AddHostedService<IFileWatcherService, FileWatcherService>();
services.AddHostedService<IFailedTradesWorker, FailedTradesWorker>();

var fileWatcher = serviceProvider.GetService<FileWatcherService>();
var tradeWorker = serviceProvider.GetService<FailedTradesWorker>();
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to remove the tradeServiceProvider line as it was part of my experiments. However, with that line removed, the same error persists